# unit testing, how far to take it when black box testing?

Tags: unit-testing, oop

Greetings,

I ran into a odd question.

I believe when testing code, you drop in parameters x, y, z into a function, you need to test the output to insure that the work was done properly.  But what if your code uses a facade pattern or contacts an "internal" source that you can query, but that would quickly causes tight coupling issues in the test code.

Here is a example:

```
class Notifier

  def send_notification action_string
    # contact messaging server and deliver message
  end

end

class DoSpecialStuff

  def my_method
    code.. code..
    n = Notifier.new
    n.send_notification "WOOT"
  end

end
```

Now, DoSpecialStuff.my_method doens't have any output, but the Notifier which is meant to abstract the "complexity" of where the output goes!  Thus resulting in an untestable function!

Do we test this code by doing this?

```
def test
  assert_no_execption_raised do # hurm... a test in name only?
    o = DoSpecialStuff.new
    o.my_method
  end
end
```

Now, we **can** check where this message goes, but that takes away from the point of the facade object, we're **trying** to hide complexity.

We **can** test the output, but **should** we?  What is right and proper?

-daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to always keep in mind that the point of testing is to give you confidence that your code works, and will continue to work in the future.

This looks like the sort of place where interaction testing would be useful. Mock out the Notifier in DoSpecialStuff's test so you can be sure it's using the Notifier correctly. Higher up you may need to mock out DoSpecialStuff to test code that sits on top of it.

Comment: But when Mock'ing (urhm) objects, out in less "meta" languages such as ruby, you then have to pass in the notifier or pass it in from some where you can control.  This is because the Notifier object is created directly inside the class.  This works for ruby (cheers!) , but what is a good and general policy.

Comment: The precise mechanisms you can use to facilitate mocking vary from language to language. Like you mentioned, dynamic languages like Ruby (and Python) often support "monkey patching". In languages that don't you generally need to add some way to replace to to-be-mocked object in the class you want to test. One option is to have a constructor that takes a Notifier. Another option is to construct the notifier using the factory method pattern, and in your test override this method to create a mock Notifier. Search for "dependency injection" and you'll find some other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

[to allow your tests/code to scale neatly you should decouple your code using an interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing#Separation_of_interface_from_implementation), this makes updating tests after refactoring much simpler, [otherwise by coupling your code you incur technical debt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) you could potentially add

1. interface to decouple the code
2. a mock for DoSpecialStuff to test that the decoupled code behaves as you expect

if you where writing the code in C++ it would look something like

Notifiers Code

```
Notifier.h
class Notifier : public I_Notifier
{
    void _sendNotification( NotificationInstance * notification );
};

Notifier.cpp
void Notifier::_sendNotification( NotificationInstance * notification ) 
{
  //do some stuff that needs testing 
}
```

Interface to the Notifier, this is what gets added to the DoSpecialStuff class to decouple the code
    I_Notifier.h

```
class I_Notifier
{
    void sendNotification( NotificationInstance * notification ) { _sendNotification(notification); }
    virtual void _sendNotification( NotificationInstance * notification )=0;
}
```

Mock used for testing aspects of DoSpecialStuff, our mock assumes that the notifiers code works our ***unit tests for DoSpecialStuff just want to make sure sendNotification got called***, so our test can just check the state of send_notification_called to see if it was successful or not.

```
Mock_Notifier.h
struct Test_Notifier : public I_Notifier
{
  Test_Notifier() : send_notification_called(false)

  virtual void _sendNotification( NotificationInstance * instance ) 
  {
    send_notification_called = true;
  }
  bool send_notification_called;
};
```

DoSpecialStuff code ***Note that this class now has an interface to the notifier class*** which is what decouples the code (so our test no longer needs to include the actual class unless we are using calls from it

```
DoSpecialStuff.cpp
class DoSpecialStuff
{
  DoSpecialStuff( I_Notifier * n ) : notifier_(n) {}
  void DoSpecialStuff::_myMethod( NotificationInstance * notification ) 
  I_Notifier * notifier_;
}

void DoSpecialStuff::_myMethod( NotificationInstance * notification ) 
{
  //do some stuff that needs testing
  n.send_notification (notification )
}
```

Interface

```
I_DoSpecialStuff.h
class I_DoSpecialStuff
{
    void myMethod( NotificationInstance * notification ) { _myMethod(notification); }
    virtual void _myMethod( NotificationInstance * notification )=0;
}
```

Where the functionality is

- contact messaging server and deliver message

on top of your unit tests you would also have a set of functional tests, so the unit tests would test each method of the classes (where appropriate), the functional test suite would start up an instance of your server and then the functional tests would call the functions that would contact the messaging server, then check the output (be it a database state or returned signal)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that may better suit your situation is move instantiation, and in your example possibly the method call, of the collaborating class to another method as such:

```
class DoSpecialStuff

  def my_method
    code.. code..
    send_notification        
  end

  def send_notifier
    n = Notifier.new
    n.send_notification "WOOT"
  end

end
```

Forgive me if my syntax is wrong, whatever language this is (Ruby?), I am not familiar.

Now to test, extend `DoSpecialStuff` and **override** `send_notification` so that it either does nothing or you can verify it was called with your test (I'm assuming there's some way of throwing a global variable around or some such).